# How can I set the server date as current Date in jQuery datpicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

i use the jQuery Plugin datepicker and I don´t want the user to be able to change the Today Date on his client. So I was wondering how I can set the Today Date (not the selected date!) to my server date. The code below i.e. just sets the default "SELECTED" date value

```
defaultDate: myServerDate
```

...i also tried this:

```
myDatepicker.datepicker('setDate', myServerDate);
```

Both attempts just end up with selecting those dates by default. But none of actually really changes the date of today.

Cheers, sash

Comment: What value does your server put in to `myServerDate` ? (an example)

Comment: it´s a string like "20.09.2012". (My dateFormat is set to "dd.mm.yy")

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it this isn't possible without hacking `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` the following is the extract from the non-minified version of that file:

```
/* Generate the HTML for the current state of the date picker. */
_generateHTML: function(inst) {
  var today = new Date();
  today = this._daylightSavingAdjust(
    new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate())); // clear time
```

As you can see from the above `today` is calculated directly from JavaScript's Date object, so there is no way to pass that value in... I guess mainly because it's quite an odd request to change the current day.

There are four soultions for this, 3 of which aren't great, I've placed them in consideration order, 1 being the best, 4 being worst / most complicated:

1. You could get involved and implement/report the feature of `setToday` yourself - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/
2. You can copy the _generateHTML function into your own code and extend it using the method stated by RodrigoCouto: 
   [jQuery DatePicker Issue: Set current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385214/jquery-datepicker-issue-set-current-date)
3. You could hack `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` to allow you to define a date in place of the code `var today = new Date();`. You should make a note of this override clearly in any comments you have within your application, so as to warn yourself (and other developers) when it is time to upgrade to the next version of jQuery UI.
4. You could build a js hack to run alongside the datepicker plugin and rewrite it's output each time it displays the calendar. i.e. detect `$('.ui-datepicker-today')` and remove that class, then recalculate where it should be placed by stepping along siblings and checking data attributes... this is the worst method as it wouldn't affect any of datepicker's internal calculations and would be complicated to accomplish.

Comment: thx for you answer. i think the _generateHTML function is just responsible for showing the selected Today Date in the Calender. But I have also a time range (last week und next week) that still refers to the clients date afer I changed the _generateHTML function with a speicial date value.

Comment: hmmm. ah well, I guess it'll have to be implemented as a feature in the plugin then before you'll to be able to change it. annoying :/